# How to remove the file suffix/extension (.jsp and .action) using the Stripes Framework?

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml, stripes

I'm looking to use pretty / clean URL's in my web app.

I would like the following URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp/calculator
```

.. to resolve to:

```
com.mydomain.myapp.action.CalculatorActionBean
```

I tried overwriting the NameBasedActionResolver with:

```
public class CustomActionResolver extends NameBasedActionResolver {
    public static final String DEFAULT_BINDING_SUFFIX = ".";

    @Override
    protected String getBindingSuffix() {
        return DEFAULT_BINDING_SUFFIX;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getActionBeanSuffixes() {
        List<String> suffixes = new ArrayList<String>(super.getActionBeanSuffixes());
        suffixes.add(DEFAULT_BINDING_SUFFIX);
        return suffixes;
    }
}
```

And adding this to `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which gets me to:

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp/Calculator.
```

But:

1. A stray "." is still neither pretty nor clean.
2. The class name is still capitalized in the URL..?
3. That still leaves me with `*.jsp`..? Is it even possible to get rid of both `.action` and `.jsp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the @URLBinding annotation.  Look at [@URLBinding](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/UrlBinding.html) on your Bean.

@UrlBinding("/calculator")

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried this, but I then get a 404 when trying to access `http://mydomain.com/myapp/calculator`. Furthermore, I'd rather be establishing my own convention, rather than configuring by exception, on an action-by-action basis.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DMF
http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/DynamicMappingFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, and had the same question, though I wanted my URL to use the trailing slash `http://mydomain.com/myapp/calculator/`

The answer is to use @UrlBinding & the DynamicMappingFilter

I modified the example to have:

```
@UrlBinding("/calculator/")
public class CalculatorActionBean implements ActionBean {
  .
  .
  .
return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/view/calculator.jsp");
```

Then I added the DMF to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>Stripes Dynamic Mapping Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DynamicMappingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.stripes</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DynamicMappingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now the clean URL works as expected, and I'm never redirected to a *.action URL after interacting with the form.